# Windows displays states in x.509 Subject fields as S=<state>

Tags: windows, x509

I've noticed that Windows will display an x.509 certificate subject as `S=some-state` rather than `ST=some-state` as is described by x.520: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1779 (Table 1).

For example:

```
$>  (Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe).SignerCertificate.Subject
CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
```

I have also parsed the same certificate programatically and have received `ST=Washington` as the output, so the underlying DER is clearly correct and the problem is in the representation.

Does anyone know why MS does this? Is it allowed by a part of the standard I have missed? I'd like to know just out of curiosity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft implementation of X.500 names supports standardized names. In addition, Microsoft implementation supports aliases. That is, particular object identifier may have multiple mappings to friendly name. For example, `StateOrProvince` RDN is mapped to three friendly names:

```
2.5.4.8 -- State Or Province (S)
  pwszName = S
  CRYPT_RDN_ATTR_OID_GROUP_ID (5)
  dwLength = 0

2.5.4.8 -- State Or Province (S)
  pwszName = ST
  CRYPT_RDN_ATTR_OID_GROUP_ID (5)
  dwLength = 0

2.5.4.8 -- State Or Province (S)
  pwszName = State Or Province
  CRYPT_EXT_OR_ATTR_OID_GROUP_ID (6)
  dwValue = 0
```

So, `OID=2.5.4.8` can be mapped to either, `S`, `ST` or `State Or Province`. And it works in opposite direction: all aliases will be translated to same OID value.

Default translation from OID to friendly name depends on OID group (when requested) and registration order (priority). In a given case, `S` alias has higher priority, than `ST`.